# python is doubling (" ") to ("" "") how can i fix this

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is an example of the code that i'm using without the website added.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import random as rd
source = requests.get('http://example.com').text
file = open('C:/xampp/htdocs/new-site/text.php', 'w')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
header = soup.find('p', class_='StoryHead').text
Program_Title = 'Program Title'
CSS = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css.css">'
start =  CSS + '<div id="yo">' + '<div id="first">' + '<h1>' + '\n' + '\n' + \
Program_Title + '\n' + header + '</h1>' + '</div id="first">'

csv_writer = csv.writer(file) 
csv_writer.writerow( start )
```

here: some of the results from the code, but as you can see the code doubles (" ")

```
"<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""./css.css""><div id=""yo""><div id=""first""> 
<h1>
```

Comment: Your code cannot be executed (there is no paragraph on example.com with the class 'StoryHead'; the file path is absolute and does not work on other computers). After I addressed those problems and saved `start` into a file as CSV, I got very different results: every character was placed into a separate column. So, I have three questions: 1. Is this _really_ the code that you used to produce and save data? 2. Why do you want to save HTML into a CSV file at all? This is a highly unusual form of storage for text in general and HTML in particular. 3. Why does the file have a PHP extension?

Comment: Please read the description before commenting ("code that i'm using without the website added"). the outcome of the project shouldn't be relevant, i outlined the problem i wish to solve, which is to change the output of ("" "") to (" "). Thank you.

Comment: What is that even supposed to mean - "without the website added"? Anyway, since you are doing something quite unusual, I thought I would ask a bunch of questions to steer you away from a possible trouble, but good luck.

Comment: I honestly would like to apologize for that, it came off a lot snappier and rude then i intended it to, I've just have been really irritated with this problem and trying to fix it. I regret the way i wrote that and hope you have a great day. Again i'm very sorry.

Comment: As DYZ already said, it doesn't make any sense to write HTML data into a `.php` file with the `csv` module. The csv writer is doubling your quotes because that's how csv escapes quotes. Why on earth *are* you using the csv module to write a string to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the CSV ability to write just to the default writing

```
file = open('C:/xampp/htdocs/new-site/text.php', 'w')
#content here
csv_writer = csv.writer(file) 
csv_writer.writerow( start )
```

To this:

```
file = open('C:/xampp/htdocs/new-site/text.php', 'w')
#content here
file.write(start)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be coming from escaping of the double quotes by the csv writer.
The default quotechar must be (").

try:

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='\\')
```

EDIT: Updated parameters to csv.writer